# Metaplex candy machine 2 unlimited sale

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I was wondering what approach one would take for minting unlimited/infinite NFTs kind of like a ticket. NFT artwork/properties would be the same.

Do I still want to use the candymachine?

It'd be nice if I could do something like this in config.json, a really large number if infinite impossible.

```
    {
      "price": 0.1,
      "number": 100000000000,
      ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

You are already planning into the right direction.

Use a very high number (datatype of the supply is u64 so technically 18446744073709551615 should be maximum) and combine it with hiddensettings to rent cost.

More info info on hiddensettings here https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#hidden-settings

Comment: Something isn't clear also is if I have a number say a million. Do I have to create million json/png pairs in assets? Is there a way to specify just one such file pair?

Comment: No, with hidden settings and the js cli you only need one filepair